# Запрос к MySQL с выводом в том порядке, в котором был ввод where

Tags: python, mysql

Как составить запрос, который делает вот что:

Есть таблица

```
col1 col2

1111 aaaa
1111 bbbb
2222 eeee
2222 xxxx
2222 aaaa
5555 yyyy
```

есть входящие рандомные данные, собранные в список от 0 до 1000 элементов:

```
list = dddd, yyee, hhhh, aaaa, ccnc, eeee,.... размер списка от 0 до 400 килобайт

list[0] = dddd
list[1] = yyee
...
```

запрос:
select * from table where col2 in (здесь элементы списка строго по порядку: dddd, yyee, hhhh, aaaa, ccnc, eeee,....)

ответ:
надо получить КОРТЕЖ, соответствующий порядку элементов в where.

например, запрос:

```
select * from table where col2 in (dddd, yyee, hhhh, aaaa, ccnc, eeee)
```

должен дать такой ответ:

```
uuuu = [ [none], [none], [none], [ [(1111)(aaaa)], [(2222),(aaaa)] ], [none], [(5555),(yyyy)] ]

где есть строгое соответствие элементов и результатов:
uuuu[0] = where[0] = dddd = list[0] = none
uuuu[1] = where[2] = yyee = list[1] = none
uuuu[2] = where[3] = hhhh = list[2] = none
uuuu[3] = where[3] = aaaa = list[3] = [ [(1111)(aaaa)], [(2222),(aaaa)] ]
uuuu[4] = where[4] = ccnc = list[4] = none
uuuu[5] = where[5] = eeee = list[5] = [(5555),(yyyy)]
```

другими словами, порядок элементов в where in (dddd, yyee, hhhh, aaaa, ccnc, eeee) соответствует порядку элементов в ответе от mysql

я думаю, можно реализовать с помощью переменных SQL на входе и на выходе

Comment: Что-то мне кажется вы сами себе зачем-то усложняете задачу. Смысл то всего этого какой?

Comment: смысл - увеличить скорость обработки данных, уменьшив количество запросов к БД

Comment: Значения во WHERE не являются набором данных и не могут быть использованы для обработки данных.

Answer (score 1):

Принципиально два решения - оба в общем плохие.

Первый - передать список дважды в виде единого CSV литерала и использовать в отборе и в сортировке.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(column, @CSV_list)
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(column, @CSV_list)
```

Второй - переданный литерал-список преобразовать в набор записей и использовать в запросе. Тут больше подойдёт не CSV, а JSON array.

```sql
SELECT table.*
FROM table
JOIN JSON_TABLE( @JSON_array_list,
                 '$[*]' COLUMNS ( sorting_order INT FOR ORDINALITY,
                                  value VARCHAR(255) PATH '$' ) ) jsontable
    ON table.column = jsontable.value
ORDER BY jsontable.sorting_order
```

Третье решение наилучшее. Список загрузить во временную таблицу, создать индекс по полю, и использовать в запросе.